# Custom Deep learning Layer is giving an Error (Custom Reshape Layer is not working)

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am using CNN of time series data from 8 channels with 500-time samples. My Deep learning architecture consists of the following layers. In the First step i perform 1D convolution across the channels (input size [500 8 1 ])so I get 16, [500 x 1 ] arrays and the output size becomes [500 x 1 x 16]. 
I wrote a custom function to reshape its size to [500 x 16 ] but it gives me an error when I train the network. 
please just see the pictures and help me out. I have tried my best to explain it as far as I can. Thanks

The Architecture  Image:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/238391/Picture1.png

When I Analyzed the network using analyzeNetwork(layers). It showed that my Architecture is correct Here are the results of it 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/238392/Capture.jpeg

But When I start training the Network It gives me the following error 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/238393/Capture.jpeg

Here is the code to the Reshape Layer which I wrote:

```
classdef reshapeLayer < nnet.layer.Layer
    properties
    end

    methods
        function layer = reshapeLayer(Name) 
            layer.Name = Name; 
        end

        function [Z] = predict(layer, X)
            sz = [size(X,1) size(X,2)*size(X,3) size(X,4)];
            Z  = reshape(X , sz);
        end

        function [dldx]  = backward(layer,~,~,dldz,~)
            sz = [size(dldz,1) , 1 , size(dldz,2) , size(dldz,3)];
            dldx = reshape(dldz , sz);
        end 
    end
end
```